# Tutorials about annotaions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, annotations

Is there any tutorial to learn annotations in Objective-C? I mean annotations like `@required`.

Please provide links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ObjC.pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf&ei=OTuSTdC0A5P4swPb6O3bDg&usg=AFQjCNFGEwwRM3299v_4JOPynpMsJVsTzQ)